# Iterate through already existing array with multiple null values and fill the non null values with a specific String

Tags: java, arrays, loops, nullpointerexception, null

so my issue is that I have this method here:

```java
public static String[][][][] inflate(String[][][][] f) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= f.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= f[i].length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= f[i][j].length; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l <= f[i][j][k].length; l++) {
                    if (f[i][j][k][l] != null) {
                        f[i][j][k][l] = "/" + (l) + "|" + (k) + "|" + (j) + "|" + (i) + "\\";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return f;
}
```

And as the title says the 4 dimensional String array called f is given and already has some null values in it. Now I want to iterate through this array and I always check if the object is null or not and if it is not I want to fill it with the given String. But my problem here is that I get an `NullPointerException` because at some point my method has `k = 3` because the length of my array counts in the null values as well obv. It will lead to this Exception since `f[i][j][k][l]` with `k = 3` does simply not exist. So how do I deal with this issue of wanting to iterate through it but at he same time I feel like I cannot use `f.length` as termination condition.

I can obv provide more info if needed but I think this should be enough to understand the situation.

Comment: The simplest way would be to put all but your outer most loop inside an if-conditional block where you check for null. eG: `if (f[i] != null) { for(int j=0; j <= f[i].length; j++) {....} }`

Comment: You probably need to do a check in every dimension: `if(f[i] != null) { loop { if(f[i][j] != null) { loop` and so on

Comment: start with making all those <= into <. IT won't address the core issue, but it's needed

Comment: then I think I would write a custom length method that returns 0 or -1 when passed null and array.length otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if [`nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) at each level of nesting. Something like this:

```java
IntStream.range(0, f.length)
    .filter(i -> Objects.nonNull(f[i]))
    .forEach(i -> IntStream.range(0, f[i].length)
        .filter(j -> Objects.nonNull(f[i][j]))
        .forEach(j -> IntStream.range(0, f[i][j].length)
            .filter(k -> Objects.nonNull(f[i][j][k]))
            .forEach(k -> IntStream.range(0, f[i][j][k].length)
                .filter(l -> Objects.nonNull(f[i][j][k][l]))
                .forEach(l -> f[i][j][k][l] =
                    "/" + (l) + "|" + (k) + "|" + (j) + "|" + (i) + "\\"))));
```